# Italic for wsuipa Phonetic Symbols

Tags: symbols, italic

Is it possible to produce ʂ (command `\tails`) in italic style? When I use `{\textit \tails}`, an error occurs:

> LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/ipa/m/it' in size <10> not available
>   (Font)              Font shape`U/ipa/m/sl' tried instead on input line 47.
>
> ! Font U/ipa/m/it/10=wslipa10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
>   nd.  relax

I use the latest MiKTeX version, pdflatex, in the preamble I have

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ipa}
```

Actually, before the today upgrade of MiKTeX, the combination `{\it \tails}` worked properly.

Comment: `\textit{\tails}` works with the braces as such, which is to say, that `\textit` needs a braced argument.  To use a syntax like you show, one would need `{\itshape\tails}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But both the combinations do not change anything. I can add some relevant output, which is shown in console (it is the same in all three cases):

(C:\Users\SSVergeles\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\source\public\wsuipa\iromanu.mf [20] [30] [42] [58] [43] [75] [74] [87] [88] [93] [86]) ) )

(see the transcript file for additional information)

Font metrics written on wslipa10.tfm.

Output written on wslipa10.600gf (128 characters, 22840 bytes).

Transcript written on wslipa10.log.

METAFONT failed for some reason

Sorry, but maketfm did not succeed.

Comment: Perhaps your font installation is corrupted in some way??

Comment: The command `\it` (and the similar ones such as `\bf`) have been deprecated for more than 20 years. Are you sure you want to use the bitmap fonts provided with `ipa` instead of the Type1 fonts coming with `tipa`? Anyway, if you get that error message, it means your TeX system is corrupt.

Comment: "It means your TeX system is corrupt" -- it seems the most reasonable version. I've uninstalled 64bit version, installed 32bit one. The problem did not disappeared. May be, this is a problem of the newest MiKTeX varsion? After I changed to TeXLive, the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by properly installing the TeX software

Answer (score 0):

One has to be careful of the difference between `\textit` which takes a braced argument, and `\itshape` which is a mere declaration that takes no argument.  A declaration like `\itshape` can be limited in scope by enclosing the scope in a group (i.e., braces).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ipa}
\begin{document}
\tails{}

{\itshape\tails}

\textit{\tails}
\end{document}
```

[image]